# Scatter plot with labels java

Tags: java, scatter

I need to create a scatter plot in Java, which shows a label in a point position. For example, I have a plot with a point in position (10,20), I need to show a string in that position of the plot instead of a colored point. Is this possible using some library? I have been trying with JChart2D, JFreeChart without success, I just get normal scatter plots.

Thanks for your time.